# Check any string from a set of substrings available in main String in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, substring, cell-array

We have set of sub strings `t = (b6,b7,y7,y8)` and a  main String `K ='hgtb6ju\u'`.

I need to check whether any of the element in `t` available in `K`. If yes, which substring(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = {'b6', 'b7', 'y7', 'y8', 'ju'};
K = 'hgtb6ju\u';
logidx = ~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(K,t)); %Finding if substrings are present
matched = t(logidx)  % Finding which substrings are present
```

Comment: I just was about to update my answer with the regexp variant :) Made some tic-toc, this one is much faster.

Comment: Thank You!!   One more clarification required, if t = {'b10', 'b1','b11'};
K = 'hgtb10ju\u'; . is there any way to distinguish b10 from b1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strfind`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com):

```
t = {'b6', 'b7', 'y7', 'y8', 'ju'};
K = 'hgtb6ju\u';
indexes = find(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(K, x)), t));
% indexes == [1, 5] - means: 'b6' and 'ju'
isAny = ~isempty(indexes);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thanks, you are totally right! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter than the strfind solution (if you have access to R2016b):

```
K = 'hgtb6ju\u';
t = {'b6', 'b7', 'y7', 'y8', 'ju'};
indices = find(cellfun(@(s) contains(K,s),t));
```

You can even call `contains(K,t)` directly, but it will only return a scalar logical indicating whether *any* of the elements of `t` is in `K`, not telling you which. That's what above's cellfun call does.